# Creating a summary table violates a restriction

Tags: db2, materialized-views

I'm trying to union two MQTs containing in a MQT.

```
CREATE SUMMARY TABLE MYUNIONEDTABLE 
    AS (
    SELECT * FROM MQT1
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT * FROM MQT2
    )
    DATA INITIALLY DEFERRED REFRESH DEFERRED
    ORGANIZE BY ROW;
```

Which leads to the following error:

> The statement failed because the fullselect specified for the materialized query table "MYUNIONEDTABLE" violates a restriction. Reason code = "2".. SQLCODE=-20058, SQLSTATE=428EC, DRIVER=4.18.60

The `SELECT` statement itself works fine.

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you check the [Info Center article](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.messages.sql.doc/doc/msql20058n.html?cp=SSEPGG_9.7.0%2F2-6-27-20-49) on this error?

> ### SQL20058N
>
> The statement failed because the fullselect specified for the
>   materialized query table table-name violates a restriction. Reason
>   code = *reason-code*.
>
> **Explanation**
>
> Restrictions apply to the contents of a fullselect used in the
>   definition of a materialized query table. Some restrictions are based
>   on the materialized query table options, such as REFRESH DEFERRED or
>   REFRESH IMMEDIATE. Other restrictions are based on whether or not the
>   table is replicated. The fullselect in the statement that returned
>   this condition violates at least one of these restrictions.
>
> If this message is returned during the creation of a staging table,
>   the error applies to the query used in the definition of the
>   materialized query table with which the staging table is associated.

Reason code 2, as your error message shows, means:

```
The fullselect referenced an unsupported object type.
```

Take a look at the [article for MQT restrictions](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.perf.doc/doc/c0060899.html?cp=SSEPGG_9.7.0%2F2-3-2-9-6-0) to see what statement you are using that is unsupported.

Comment: The links don't work anymore, but this is the section of the current docs that has info on the error code and helped me resolve a similar issue: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=messages-sql20000-sql20249#sql20058n